# Cytoscape.js get node position from dagre layout

Tags: cytoscape.js, dagre

In order to make zigzag like edges I need to make some calculations and for that I need every node's position on the layout and I am having some trouble achieving that.

I am trying to get the node's position this way:

```
cy.$('#1891').position()
```

but no matter which `id` I use, I always get `{x: 0, y: 0}` values.

When I add an event like this:

```
cy.on('mouseover', 'node', function(evt){
    var node = evt.target;
    console.log(node.position());
});
```

I get every node's postion.

What would be the right way of getting every node's position from `dagre` layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.

It was a silly mistake by me. I was trying to get the node's position before the layout was applied. Putting the `cy.$('#1891').position();` after the  `layout.run();` did the trick.